# Separate an advanced model into two sections

Tags: modeling

I need to separate the leaves of an apple tree from its trunk. The only thing defining the two is that they both have a different texture, so I wondered if there is any way to manage to separate the two? Currently I have this 'export selected' add-on: https://github.com/dairin0d/export-selected
Which I plan to use to separate the two objects into different .blend files.

I'm not certain on how else to do this as the model is quite a mess vertex wise:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
thanks.

Comment: If trunk consists of linked geometry then it will be easier to select its vertex and run Ctrl+L to select linked geometry of the trunk and then invert the selection with Ctrl+I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on [j.akshat's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/87955/38670):

If you have only the two materials/textures and want to do it the easy way, you can <kbd>Tab</kbd> into edit mode and press <kbd>P</kbd> *(Separate)* > *Material*.

If you want a bit more control:

- Go into face select mode.
- Select any face with the material/texture you want to separate.
- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> *(Select Similar)* > *Material* in the resultant pop-up.
- Press <kbd>P</kbd> > *Selection*.

After you do this, you can open another (or a new) .blend file and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to import the object from the first file.

Comment: Thank you all for the fast answers. This one worked the best for me.

Comment: You're quite welcome, @92carmnad. Glad I could help.

Comment: @RayMairlot, thanks for the keyboard formatting. I wasn't quite sure how to do those.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way.If they have different textures then you must have applied two different materials.Then you can go in edit mode and select the leaves by material and separate them.[image]

Answer (score 0):

The laves faces seems to be a way much larger than the trunk faces.
Select similar(cntrl + G) by face area might work adjusting the threshold.